# Hide typing in Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to be able to paste a bunch of commands into the command prompt, but NOT show the commands that I'm typing (responses from the commands can show though).

I know this is easy to do with a batch file, but I have been given some specific requirements that the commands be copy/pasted into the command prompt.  I hate seeing all of that extra junk show up and looks ugly and confusing to end users.

I swear there was some @ command or something to do this, but I can't for the life of me remember what it is now.

Comment: The @ command you're thinking about is for silencing the output of commands from a batch script.  If you're copying into command prompt, I don't see how it can't show up (with stock cmd).

Comment: @armani it can be done. Writing my answer as I type this. :)

Comment: Also the command is `@echo off` which is for batch scripts, not for the command line itself.

Comment: The `@` prefix suppresses output ('turns echo off') for any command that follows, not just `@echo off`.  It's just most commonly *used*  as `@echo off` to shut off echoing for an entire script.

Comment: I know about the echo off and the "@" symbol.  This was something different...  think it had Local in the name...  Now that I'm thinking about it though, I'm wondering if it was just for telnet...

Answer (score 0):

When you have your command prompt open, click the command icon in the top left of the window to access the menu.

Choose `Properties` to access the properties.

Click the dark grey color (8th one) between the light grey and blue color)

Set the Red, Green and Blue values all to 0, to create a 2nd black color.

This is to be able to do this on command next time if you want.

Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> to go back to the command prompt.

Now the following command will hide all info:

```
color 08
```

You can type what you want, but the output and what you type is all black.

Type CLS to clear the screen when you're done.

Type `color 07` to restore it to black, grey and see how the entire screen is readable again (including what was previously posted).

To be sure you cannot retreive the commands, close the command screen by typing `exit` or clicking the [x].

Comment: `color 08` is very visible on my cmd, and I get this msg from helpfile: `The COLOR command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if an attempt is made to execute
the COLOR command with a foreground and background color that are the
same.`

Comment: @Zimba then you have not followed the instruction to the letter. You have to use `color 08` AND you have to alter the color values for the dark grey color in properties and you get black on black. The command prompt will think it is readable while it really is not. I just tested this on Windows 10 20H2 x64

Answer (score -1):

The "@ command" you speak of is `@echo off` added to beginning of batch files to hide command/contents of batch file from being displayed on command prompt/console during execution.

If you want "the commands be copy/pasted into the command prompt" without being displayed on execution, put them in command blocks (surrounded by brackets)

eg.

```
(
echo off
cls
set /p name="Who's that? "
echo Never heard of any !name! in this town!
REM process launch sequence of Russian missile
echo I'm off to Mars.
ping -n 4 localhost > nul
for /l %i in (5,-1,0) do (
cls
echo %i
ping -n 3 localhost > nul
)
cls & echo See ya!
)
.
```

Tested on Win 10

Comment: I have to vote this down. OP specificalyl asks to hide text inputted into command prompt and cannot use batch scripts.

Comment: @LPChip: This is NOT a batch script. OP asked for commands not to be visible to "end users" on command prompt upon execution. This is done by command blocks, shown in posted answer

Comment: Its technically still a batch script, because you copy the script, paste it, the script is visible until you hit enter. Also, commandline has a fixed length of characters you can type, which this is going to exceed.

Comment: @LPChip, This is not exceeding any characters, and commands are not visible. No need to press anything, no enter. Just copy/paste. Try it. I've tested it, have you? OP aim is to not confuse end users. My command block doesn't wait to press enter. The `color` command in your answer is visible to end user.